# Is the following Hibernate custom ID generator code correct?

Tags: java, hibernate, transactions

I just created a custom hibernate ID generator, and since I'm not an hibernate expert I would like to get some feedback on my code. The generated ID is `select max(id) from table`, +1.

```
public class MaxIdGenerator implements IdentifierGenerator, Configurable {

    private Type identifierType;
    private String tableName;
    private String columnName;

    @Override
    public void configure(Type type, Properties params, Dialect dialect) {
        identifierType = type;
        tableName = (String) params.getProperty("target_table");
        columnName = (String) params.getProperty("target_column");
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized Serializable generate(SessionImplementor session,
            Object object) {
        return generateHolder(session).makeValue();
    }

    protected IntegralDataTypeHolder generateHolder(SessionImplementor session) {
        Connection connection = session.connection();
        try {
            IntegralDataTypeHolder value = IdentifierGeneratorHelper
                .getIntegralDataTypeHolder(identifierType
                        .getReturnedClass());
            String sql = "select max(" + columnName + ") from " + tableName;
            PreparedStatement qps = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
            try {
                ResultSet rs = qps.executeQuery();
                if (rs.next())
                    value.initialize(rs, 1);
                else
                    value.initialize(1);
                rs.close();
            } finally {
                qps.close();
            }
            return value.copy().increment();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new IdentifierGenerationException(
                    "Can't select max id value", e);
        }
    }
    }
```

I'd like to know:

1. How can I make this **multi-transaction-safe**? (ie if two concurrent transactions insert data, how can I safely assume that I will not end-up having twice the same ID?) -- I guess the only solution here would be to prevent two concurrent hibernate transaction to run at the same time if they use the same generator, is this possible?
2. If the code **could be improved**: I feel wrong having to use hard-coded `"select"`, `"target_column"`, etc...

To guarantee point 1), I can fallback if necessary on synchronizing inserts on my java client code.

*Please do not comment on the reasons why I'm using this kind of generator: legacy code still insert data onto the same database and uses this mechanism... and can't be modified. And yes, I know, it sucks.*

Answer (score 2):

I think the easiest way to achive a transaction-safe behaviour is to put the code you use to retrive the maximum id and do the insert statement, in a transactional block.
Something like:

```
Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
//some code...
transaction.commit();
session.close()
```

I also recommend to use HQL (Hibernate Query Language) to create the query, instead of native sql where possible. Moreover, from your description, I have understood that you expect from the query a unique result, the maximum id. So, you could use uniqueResult() method over your query instead of executeQuery.

Answer (score 0):

you can use AtomicInteger for generating ID. That can be used by many threads concurrently.

If you are free to use any other provider of ID then i will suggest to use UUID class for generating random ID.

```
UUID.randomUUID();
```

You can refer to [link](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=56) which contain some other ways to generate ID.